# Error on spring boot web application startup with weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

Starting the spring boot as java application by clicking the file having the main method and below is the error I am getting, configured weblogic server and the application type is war , even when i changed to jar the same exception is coming

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
```

how to configure EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean for weblogic server I'm not getting can somebody help me .... Thanks

below is my main class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.entity"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example.demo"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})


public class DemoApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
          return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
       }


}
```

I have excluded all tomcat jars in the pom.xml

```
2017-07-26 20:36:58.350 ERROR 1600 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:36) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace. Also remove `@EnableWebMvc` and `@Configuration` (spring boot does all that for you), that also applies to `@PropertySource` spring boot already loads that file for you. If your `DemoApplication` class is in the `com.example.demo` package (which is recommended` you can remove all other annotations as well and only leave the `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: @M Deinum , thanks for responding updated the full stacktrace